# Recording video from the PR2

Tags: ros, pr2, image-transport, video, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I was wondering if there were any pre-built tools for recording video streams from the PR2's camera.

I need to record video that I can synchronize to sensor signals from the PR2's gripper as well as arm command signals.  I have recorded a bag file, and used  use "extract_images" from the "image_view" stack as described in the rosbag tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data  However, this approach seems to skip frames, even when I set the parameter _sec_per_frame:=0.0001.

Is there a direct way of creating video (preferably from the compressed or theora messages) or a way that guarantees no missed frames, or at least accounts for the missed frame in the timeline of the video (so that it can maintain synchronization with the other data)?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10489/recording-video-from-the-pr2/) by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I once made a small video_to_bag and a bag_to_video package, it's on our [git](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/opencv_additions.git) it is not optimal yet, it could use some timing and camera calibration extension, so patches are highly appreciated! But perhaps it is suitable for your task.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1